# How can I pass command line arguments to sed?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line, sh

I am trying to update a deb control file via my make process so that I dont need to manually update it every time. The file has one line: `Installed-Size: 123`. I want to replace 123 with the actual size of the install.

So far I have two pieces: `du -s FOLDER` which gets me the size i need and `sed -i "s/Install-Size: .*/Install-Size: 321/" FOLDER/DEBIAN/control`. The problem is that I need to get the first part of the output from du into the replace string for sed. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

```
 sed -i "s/Install-Size: .*/Install-Size: $(du -s FOLDER | cut -f1)/" FOLDER/DEBIAN/control
```

Comment: Doesn't that include the folder name as well as the size? Also, in general, it is better to use the `$(du -s FOLDER | sed 's/ .*//')` notation in place of back-ticks.

Comment: Edited to not include the folder name

Comment: `sh -c` is unnecessary within `$()` notation.